# Is the Artinian property dual to the Noetherian property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

If $R$ is a ring and $M$ is a left $R$-module, we say that $M$ is Noetherian whenever it satisfies any of the equivalent conditions:

1N. Every ascending (under subspace inclusion) chain of submodules of $M$ stabilises,

2N. Every non-empty collection of submodules of $M$ has a maximal element under subspace inclusion,

3N. Every submodule of $M$ is finitely generated.

Whilst we say that $M$ is Artinian whenever it satisfies either of the equivalent conditions:

1A. Every descending (under subspace inclusion) chain of submodules of $M$ stabilises,

2A. Every non-empty collection of submodules of $M$ has a minimal element under subspace inclusion.

It seems to be that conditions 1N and 1A are dual, whilst conditions 2N and 2A are also dual. However I can't seem to think of a property of Artinian modules that seems obviously dual to condition 3N.

My question is whether or not there does exist such a condition?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that if a ring is Artinian then it is Noetherian, so that while the definitions may look dual to one another, in fact the Artinian condition (for a *ring*, thought of either as a left or right module over itself) is *much* stronger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is whether or not there does exist such a condition?

Yes. 3A should be

> Every quotient module of $M$ is **finitely cogenerated**.

Finite cogeneration is easy to understand if you first rephrase finite generation this way:

> A module is finitely generated if for every chain of submodules $N_0\subseteq N_1\subseteq N_2\ldots$ such that $\cup_{i\in I} N_i=M$, there is necessarily a finite subset $F\subseteq I$ such that $\cup_{i\in F} N_i=M$.

Then

> A module is finitely cogenerated if for every chain of submodules $N_0\supseteq N_1\supseteq N_2\ldots$ such that $\cap_{i\in I} N_i=\{0\}$, there is necessarily a finite subset $F\subset I$ such that $\cap_{i\in F} N_i=\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. I was reading over the definition of Noetherian and Artinian (I saw the Noetherian property before the Artinian property, and so in my head I just parsed Artinian as "dual to Noetherian") but seeing the definitions written down I found it odd that the Noetherian property had three equivalent definitions, but the Artinian property only had two. I wonder why learning resources do not often state this definition of Artinian.

Comment: I imagine it's because cogeneration isn't as common as generation? I wonder if this alternate definition is ever useful. Thanks again!

Comment: @AdamHiggins Yes, it is probably just not as often mentioned. It’s well covered in books like Lam’s and Anderson & Fuller

Comment: @AdamHiggins To address your more general question, one should say that the definitions of Noetherian and Artinian are certainly dual (in terms of chain conditions and min/max conditions) but not every theorem about them dualizes.